# Corrupt SVN repository: svnadmin: Malformed file and Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

Tags: svn, corrupt

I was working on a project for couple of months and stored the files on a SVN repository. I created the repository on my DropBox (www.dropbox.com/) folder, so that I can work both from my home and from the lab. But recently, my repository became corrupted. Whenever I try to checkout files from the repository I get the following error (There are also some other projects that are working perfectly):

```
Couldn't open a repository
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///Users/USER_NAME/Dropbox/svnrepos/PROJECT_NAME'
No such file or directory
svn: Can't open file '/Users/USER_NAME/Dropbox/svnrepos/PROJECT_NAME/db/uuid': No such file or directory
```

Then I look for solutions to recover revisions from a corrupted SVN repository. I have tried to dump the repository but receive the following error:

```
svnadmin: Malformed file
```

The uuid file is empty and .../db/current file contain value 45. Can anyone help me to recover my revisions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing is that Dropbox will allow to rollback to previous versions. I faced also few times some issues with SVN.

My suggestion would be: 1st make a copy of the current repo so it is safe. Then try to rollback [with dropbox] to the day before you had problems. You can do this from the Dropbox web interface.

At this point you would have to copy the new files in the SVN and commit again.

Comment: THANKS. I was not informed about the rollback feature. Pretty nice. Trying to rollback the file now.

Comment: I tried to rollback but the problem is that the repository corrupted before the oldest version to which dropbox support rollback